# QT5 connect signal to function

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

So, I'm looking to make a button that becomes flat when pressed in QT5. I've read this
https://woboq.com/blog/new-signals-slots-syntax-in-qt5.html
and it seems that I should be able to do this without making my own button class. So, I've got

`QPushButton* button = new QPushButton("text", parent);
QObject::connect(button, &QPushButton::clicked, button, &QPushButton::isFlat(true));`
and I'm getting
`error: call to non-static member function without an object argument`
My questions are; am I reading this new syntax wrong? Can I only connect to static functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to connect a method of no instance, use a `lambda` for example for capture the button instance:

```
QObject::connect(button, &QPushButton::clicked, button, 
                 [&button]() {button->setFlat(true)});
```

**Not tested.**

Comment: Got me on the right track I think.  
`[&button]() {button->setFlat(true);}`     
Should be setflat (my bad). This compiles but also crashes on button press.

Comment: Got it. Now using `[=]() {button->setFlat(true);}` as the final parameter and all is well. You're the man man!